# How to specify memory per process in an array job in slurm?

Tags: memory, out-of-memory, job-scheduling, slurm

I want to run thousands of identical single-thread simulations with different random seeds (which I pass to my program). Some of them have gone out of memory, yet I don't know why. I call `run_batch_job` as `sbatch --array=0-999%100 --mem=200M run_batch_job`, where `run_batch_job` contains:

```
#!/bin/env bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=1  # Number of cores
#SBATCH --nodes=1  # All cores on one machine

srun my_program.out $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
```

For a single thread, 200M should be more than enough memory, yet for some simulations, I get the error:

```
slurmstepd: error: Exceeded step memory limit at some point.
slurmstepd: error: Exceeded job memory limit at some point.
srun: error: cluster-cn002: task 0: Out Of Memory
slurmstepd: error: Exceeded job memory limit at some point.
```

Am I allocating 200M to each of the thousand threads, or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I've tried specifying `--cpus-per-task=1` and `--mem-per-cpu=200M` instead of `--ntasks=1`, `--nodes=1` and `--mem=200M`, with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Your submission is correct, but 200M might be low depending on the libraries you use or the files you read. Request at least 2G as virtually all clusters have at least 2GB of memory per core.

Comment: On my machine, the program takes 20MB of resident memory. Do you mean that the memory errors occured due to the fact compiling on the cluster somehow results in a program with more than 10 times the memory footprint? (Could be the case for all I know, I am no expert, and the cluster has Intel chips instead of amd, but I compile with the same command.)

Comment: The memory needed for the job comprises more than just the memory footprint of the program: buffers, caches, libraries, etc.

Comment: But if I check htop on my local workstation, it gives a number less than 20MB. This misses buffers, caches, etc?

Comment: Btw, I don't understand the `--nodes=1` option. What does it tell me? I can observe my jobs run on different nodes, so is this option not taken into account? Isn't it better to specify `--cpus-per-task` and `--mem-per-cpu` here? (Regardless of the out-of-memory issue.) And what is `--ntasks`? Doesn't every instance of `srun` spawn by definition one "task?"

Comment: Yes, and that does not account for the memory needed by Bash, by srun, etc. which are all part of your job.

Comment: `--nodes=1` means 'a minimum of one node'. You are creating a job array, all jobs are independent, they are all subject to `--nodes=1`.  `--mem-per-cpu` is probably better in your case. `--ntasks`  is the number of tasks that must be spawned by `srun`. In your case one. The confusion comes from the fact that jobs in a job array are also named 'tasks', but you can create a job array of jobs that comprise several tasks each.